# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException in Xcode 8.0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I am quite to new to iOS app developing. Currently I am working on a project which was builded long time ago (I think in 2011).

I don't have much knowledge about xcode and objective C.

I have solved some of the problems but can't solved this one :(

Although many other peoples already asked this question but I can't find solution of this.

I am getting the error

```
2016-10-26 12:51:59.200 TestCordova1[12758:1094626] *** Terminating     app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-     [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc476e02be0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010310134b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010221621e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103170f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103086a2e ___forwarding___ + 526
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103086798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TestCordova1                        0x0000000101ba8810 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 304
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000103e5568e -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 290
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000103e57013 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4236
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000103e5d3b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000103e5a539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010832a76b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010832a5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010832a96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001030a6311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010308b59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010308aa86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010308a494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000103e58db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000103e5ef34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    19  TestCordova1                        0x0000000101ba5714 main + 100
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001057fb68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

My main.m file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;

}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>


@interface AppDelegate : CDVViewController {

    NSString* invokeString;
}



@property (copy)  NSString* invokeString;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainViewController.h"

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "abcPlugin.h"
#import "FileIO.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize invokeString;

- (id) init
{
    return [super init];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{



    NSArray *keyArray = [launchOptions allKeys];
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]]!=nil) 
    {
        NSURL *url = [launchOptions objectForKey:[keyArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        self.invokeString = [url absoluteString];
        NSLog(@"LEMobileApp launchOptions = %@",url);
    }


    BOOL retVal = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:Nil];

    if (retVal == YES) {
        // Set the root view controller of the window
        [self.window setRootViewController:self.viewController];

        abcPlugin* objabcPlugin = [[abcPlugin alloc] init];
        [objabcPlugin showSplashScreen];
    }

    return retVal;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
}

-(id) getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className
{
    return [super getCommandInstance:className];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    if(self.invokeString)
    {

        NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var invokeString = \"%@\";", self.invokeString];
        [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    }

    [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]     setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil]; 

// Add our custom splashscreen
    abcPlugin* objabcPlugin = [[abcPlugin alloc] init];
[objabcPlugin showSplashScreen];

     return;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:  (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:   (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    NSURLRequest * req = request;
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"about:blank"]) {
        NSLog(@"rewriting about blank");
        NSString* app = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
        NSString* Newpath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/www/index.html", app];
        NSURL* NewURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:Newpath];

        req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:NewURL];
    }


    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:req navigationType:navigationType ];
}


- (BOOL)execute:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [ super execute:command];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [ super dealloc ];
}

@end
```

> I am devloping using `cordova`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `AppDelegate` inherits from `CDVViewController`? Really? It should also respond to `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol.

Comment: `appdelegate` inherits `UIResponder` class, what you trying to do ?

Comment: I don't know much about all this... Previously AppDelegate inherits the PhoneGapDelegate..... since we are not using phonegap and only use cordova... I changed PhoneGapDelegate to CDVViewController...... I know this is dumb thing :(

Comment: I think it will work if I find proper replacement of PhoneGapDelegate. We are now using only cordova

Comment: I knew native programming, so then what you suppose to do with Xcode here ?

Comment: See basically i am working on iOS app which uses phonegap. But now i have to remove all code that uses phonegap and implement the same thing using cordova...... I know phongapDelegate is a part of phonegap framework also methods didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is a part of phoneGapDelegate... I have to do same things but using cordova

Comment: just approve edit so others can help who are developing using cordova.